# assistance recovering/reinstalling/installing ubuntu and win7

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

New computer with Windows 7 installed, I defrag, shrink, re-boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB, go to gparted and look at partitions before installing Ubuntu....for some reason Win7 is still taking up 400G of my HD!

I resized partition down with gparted, exit and yes of course I can't boot into Windows.

When I go to install Ubuntu in new large unallocated space I get a blank screen at the point you are asked what kind of installation you want.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LiveUSB, Windows 7 re-installation disk and driver disks also. The HDD currently has 3 allocated partitions: 'diag' fat16, 'recovery' ntfs and 'OS' ntfs which has a red '!' next to it.

Comment: Please read OP comment http://askubuntu.com/questions/304025/assistance-recovering-reinstalling-installing-ubuntu-and-win7#comment398006_304038

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete all your partitions and make two big partitions (or whatever you want to). One partition for Windows and another one for Linux. If you want to, create a 3º partition to save your personal files with a *NTFS* format (compatible with both platforms).

After [resize your partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions), install Windows first. And then [install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/107538/62483).

---

If you want to try to recover some file, take a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190555/how-to-recover-missing-folders-in-a-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-system)

If you have a black screen after the installation, follow the steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

---

If you're still facing troubles, the most probably is that your HDD is damage.

That is all that I can tell you. Hopefully, this will be useful.

Comment: yes cool. i normally setup 3 partitions, MS-data-ubuntu. ok so i'll try a complete reinstall.thankyou

Comment: unfortunately when i tried to resize partitions using GParted it errored out. As it stands I can't install Ubuntu and I can't get windows to boot. I'm trawling Dell and MS sites to see if I can find something.

Comment: I think that you should change your HDD

Comment: wiped and re-installed windows so now windows works. thanks for help